# Como omitir acentos y mayúsculas en un SELECT con SQL/ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

Tengo una consulta de dos tablas en ORACLE, pero los campos de ambas tablas tienen diferencias de acentos o mayúsculas y estos campos se utilizan en la comparación este es el SELECT:

```css
SELECT
    cep.tipo_identificacion,
    pgtd.det_id_detalle
FROM
    carga_excel_prueba     cep,
    pyme_gen_tip_detalle   pgtd
WHERE
    traslate(upper(cep.tipo_identificacion), 'áéíóú', 'aeiouAEIOU') = traslate(upper(pgtd.det_valor_desplegar), 'áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ',
    'aeiouAEIOU')
ORDER BY
    cep.identificacion ASC;
```

EL campo de la tabla 1 es tipo_identificacion y de la dos es det_valor_desplegar:

Tabla 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y luego me muestre el campo DET_ID_DETALLE que es el ID, pero no me hace la consulta.

Comment: Y que le pasa a ese query?

Comment: Me da error no me hace la consulta

Comment: para mi que estan mal los parentesis.. estas seguro que la funcion UPPER recibe 3 parametros????

Comment: Ya lo corregí pero tampoco funciona

Comment: Pero los parametros que usas en translate son diferentes... :/

Comment: Cada vez que digas "no funciona", trata de reemplazarlo por "hace x pero yo quiero que entre `a` y salga `b`"). Va a ser más fácil ayudar

Comment: Si uso solo UPPER no da error la ejecución, pero no carga ningún dato, por que todavia valida las tildes, por eso estaba utilizando TRASLATE, para que tambien cambie las tildes, si incorporo a la sentencia el TRASLATE, da el error ORA-00909: número de argumentos no válido.